# Insertar dato aleatorio en en formulario conectado a MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Me encuentro trabajando con un formulario de datos conectado a una base de datos de MYSQL, dichos datos son tomados con el método POST he insertados a esa base de datos ya funcional. Pero uno de los problemas que tengo es que uno de los campos de la tabla de mysql llamado "pin" tiene que ser insertado con un dato aleatorio que genero con la siguiente función. (Esto sólo me funciona si inserto los datos a otra tabla diferente con un solo campo de igual forma llamado "pin", pero quiero que se inserte en la tabla dónde tengo todos mis registros del formulario que tomo con POST).

```
<?php try{
$sqlconnection = new 
pdo('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=norma035;charset=utf8','root','');
}catch(PDOException $pe){
echo 'Cannot connect to database';
die;
}
$caracteres = '123ANBCF';
for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){
$aleatoria = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 6);
echo $aleatoria . "\n";
}
$commandtext = 'INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (pin) VALUES (:aleatoria)';
$cmd = $sqlconnection->prepare($commandtext);
$cmd->bindParam(':aleatoria', $aleatoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cmd->execute(); ?>
```

La siguiente consulta es la que utilizo originalmente para insertar los datos leídos por POST y que si introduce el usuario:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre_empresa, razon_social, 
representante_legal, email, password, numero_empleados, rango_empleados, 
categoria, estado) VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', '$razonSocial', 
'$representanteLegal', '$email', '$password', '$numeroEmpleados', 
'$rangoEmpleados', '$estado', '$arrayCategorias')";
```

Esta consulta funciona si no añado el campo que me hace falta (PIN) y que quiero que se inserte automáticamente con la variable :aleatoria (que es el dato que no inserta el usuario PIN).

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Regresa algún error? o algún mensaje?

Comment: Sencillamente no lo inserta. El resto de los datos son ingresados por el usuario y por metodo POST son leídos y si los inserta, pero este único campo no será ingresado por el usuario si no generado con esta función de arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado mi problema incluyendo la variable que se genera aleatoriamente dentro de la misma consulta y esto ha quedado así:

```
<?php
$caracteres = '123ANBCF';
for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){
$aleatoria = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 6);
echo $aleatoria . "\n";
}

 $sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre_empresa, razon_social, 
 representante_legal, email, password, numero_empleados, rango_empleados, categoria, 
 estado, pin) VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', '$razonSocial', '$representanteLegal', 
 '$email', '$password', '$numeroEmpleados', '$rangoEmpleados', '$arrayCategorias', 
 '$estado', '$aleatoria')";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejecute tu código y me funcionó perfectamente. El problema puede radicar en el campo **pin** de tu tabla, verifica si es del tipo y longitud correctos, debería ser **VARCHAR(7)** según tu código.

Por otro lado, tengo dos sugerencias que darte:

1. La forma en que estas generando datos aleatorios no es la mejor, existen métodos mas seguros y profesionales, por ejemplo, la manipulación de datos de **tiempo unix** o la generación de datos **uuid**
2. El método `bindParam` puede recibir un **cuarto parámetro**, para indicar la longitud del dato a enviar. Es recomendable siempre ponerlo para mayor seguridad.

Comment: Sencillamente no lo inserta. El resto de los datos son ingresados por el usuario y por metodo POST son leídos y si los inserta, pero este único campo no será ingresado por el usuario si no generado con esta función de arriba.

Comment: Supongamos que mi consulta queda así :                                                   $commandtext = 'INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre, email, pin) VALUES (?, ? ,:aleatoria)';                                                                          Dónde "nombre" y "email" son datos que el usuario ingresa, pero el campo "pin" será un dato insertado automáticamente con la función de arriba.

Comment: Pero yo ya tengo una consulta hecha para tomar los datos con el metodo POST que si me funciona, la cuál es:                                                                $sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre_empresa, razon_social, representante_legal, email, password, numero_empleados, rango_empleados, categoria, estado) VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', '$razonSocial', '$representanteLegal', '$email', '$password', '$numeroEmpleados', '$rangoEmpleados', '$estado', '$arrayCategorias')";                     y en esta consulta no se incluye el campo PIN por que no se cómo fusionar ambas...

Comment: Gracias Edixon Alberto

Comment: De nada @Suri Gang's Hallen

Comment: Pero déjame añadir una ultima recomendación, y es que si usas **mysqli** expones la base de datos de `sql injection`, por lo tanto, se debe filtrar cada una de las variables introducidas en la consulta para evitar este problema de seguridad.